# How do I setup Laravel on Docker for local development?

Tags: laravel, docker

I have been trying for the last few days to set up Laravael for Docker on my WSL2 enabled machine. After digging through various bloated stacks - I've tried to build my own stack for local development. My issue is I cannot both mount the uncompiled Laravel folder to the container, and also install dependencies via composer. Below are my current set of files. I cannot access the default application because `autoload.php` has not been created by composer. If I copy the files to the container via dockerfile and then proceed to run composer dependencies, I end up with a static application that will not reflect changes as I make them in VSCode.

For clarification, my goal is simply to be able to edit my Laravel application without needing to re-build the image everytime.

dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4.14-apache
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y zip unzip
# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
# Install Laravel
# VOLUME ./laravel /var/www/html
# WORKDIR /var/www/html
# RUN composer install
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile.httpd
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    volumes:
      - './laravel/public:/var/www/html'
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my_secure_pwd
      - MARIADB_USER=mydbuser
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=laravel
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=mydbuserpwd
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/laravel/sail